# $v(x)=\inf\limits_{|x-y|<1}u(y)$. Show $v$ is upper semicontinuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $u:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary, and $v(x)=\inf\limits_{|x-y|<1}u(y)$. Show $v$ is upper semicontinuous.

Let $x_0\in\{x\in\mathbb{R}:v(x)<c\}$ for $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $v(x_0)=\inf\limits_{|x_0-y|<1}u(y)<c$. To show $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:v(x)<c\}$ is open, I need to find an open ball, $B_r(x_0)\subset\{x\in\mathbb{R}:v(x)<c\}$. I was wondering how to find $r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists $y_0$ such that $u(y_0) <c$ and $|x_0-y_0| <1$. Let $r=1-|x_0-y_0|$. If $x \in B(x_0,r)$ then $|x-x_0| <r=1-|x_0-y_0|$. This implies $|y_0-x| \leq |x_0-y_0|+|x_0-x|<1$ so $v(x) \leq u(y_0) <c$. This finishes the proof.